# multiple dropdown each having multiple textboxes and using jquery change vale of textbox on selected dropdown menu value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on a project and i have

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.TripItemLst.Count; i++){
<table>
<tr>
  <td>@Html.DropDownList("Status", new SelectList(ViewBag.Campaign, "Value", "Text"), new { id="dd1"})</td>
  <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TripItemLst[i].PlanTime,new {id ="tb1"})</td>
  <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TripItemLst[i].AppTime,new {id ="tb2"})</td>
  <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TripItemLst[i].ArriveTime,new {id ="tb3"})</td>
 <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TripItemLst[i].DepartTime,new {id ="tb4"})</td>
</tr>
</table>
}
```

i am trying to change each value of textbox when i select value from drop down menu corresponding to it but i am able to change just values of textbox for just first drp down and not for all. here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


           // $('#dd1').live('change', function() 
                $('#dd1').change(function () 
            {
                var sel = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
                $(".list").show(sel);
                if (sel == 0) {

                }
                else if (sel == 1) {

                }
                else {

                }
            }).trigger('change');
        });
```

Thanks in advance. hope i am clear otherwise let me know. Thanks again

Comment: which textbox you want to put your value too..since there are multiple textbox and yes why is your if condition empty

Comment: it depends on the value that i select from dropdown list. say if i select 0 from drop down it put data into first textbox and if select 1 then it should put data into first and scond text box and this i want to do for every dropdown in the loop.lets say if it loops 5 times i will get 5 dropdowns and each having 3 values(options) and i will have 4 text boxes to change data in them for each drop down.

Comment: thanks all but i got it just changed #dd to select and using event.id

Comment: Your are ids are not right. As you are creating dropdowns and textboxs in the for loop dynamically the ids should be created by appending the iterator. i.e each control should be assigned unique id. In the for loop itself you can bind the on change event to the dropdown.

Comment: @girish i am doing that only but another problem i am getting is conflict and i resolved by using $.noconflict() but still code is unaffected. what should i do ??

Comment: Please provide the updated code so that I can have look at the exact issue you are facing.